# Do I need to set create_engine put in singleton to be like singleton?

Tags: sqlalchemy

On a server I am using combination of Tornado and SQLAlchemy.
I split project and handlers in 10 files/modules.

In every module I am using `session = Session()` and `session` to query the database.

The common part of every module looks like:

```
...
import tornado.ioloop

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, echo=False, pool_size=100, pool_recycle=3600)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
 ....
```

Do I need to ensure the engine is created via the singleton pattern?

So as to not create it in every module. Or this is an *ok* way to do things and create the engine?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`scoped_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#unitofwork-contextual) which essentially serves as a thread-local singleton, creating sessions on-demand using the provided factory function.

In one module imported by all others you write:

```
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, echo=False, pool_size=100, pool_recycle=3600)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
# or make it a Tornado Application property
```

And then either use `Session` as an explicit factory:

```
session = Session()
session.query(...)
```

Or use implicit method delegation:

```
Session.query(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! Should i be putting the `session` variable in a function to be returned as a singleton object?

Comment: Somehow the `Session` class is not going into the global scope. My application is bundled as a part of a bigger application. Is it possible to localize the scope of session only to my application?